# Changing size of Xamarin Flyout page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to make a Flyout page (previously MasterDetailPage) take up a 1/3 of the screen for the Flyout and 2/3 for Detail.

I was able to accomplish this on iOS by using a custom renderer that's a modification of the [Xamarin.Form's Flyout implementation](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/TabletShellFlyoutRenderer.cs)

But there isn't any such implementation for Android and I can't figure out how to accomplish this.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/caab66bcf9614aca0c0805d560a34e176d196e17/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/ShellFlyoutRenderer.cs

Comment: Thanks @Jason, not sure how I missed that! That class's constructor has parameters though. How do I use that inside a renderer in a Flyout page? Xamarin freaks out as soon as the page is loaded complaining that it couldn't find a default, parameterless, constructor to create the page with.

Comment: it appears that its called from ShellRenderer.  I don't know all the gory details of how it works internally

Answer (score 3):

You could use custom renderer to do that.

The renderer of `FlyoutPage` in Android is `FlyoutPageRenderer`. The following link lists the renderer and native control classes that implement each Xamarin.Forms Page type:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers

The source code of FlyoutPageRenderer:
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/5.0.0/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/AppCompat/FlyoutPageRenderer.cs

You could get the field `_flyoutLayout` in source code. Then, you could set the height and width like the code below.

```
   [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(FlyoutPage), typeof(FlyoutPageCustomRenderer))]
namespace App14.Droid
{
class FlyoutPageCustomRenderer: FlyoutPageRenderer
{
    public FlyoutPageCustomRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElement oldElement, VisualElement newElement)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(oldElement, newElement);
        var fieldInfo = GetType().BaseType.GetField("_flyoutLayout", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var _flyoutLayou = (ViewGroup)fieldInfo.GetValue(this);
        var lp = new LayoutParams(_flyoutLayou.LayoutParameters);

        lp.Width = 400;
        lp.Height = 600;

        lp.Gravity = (int)GravityFlags.Left;
        _flyoutLayou.LayoutParameters = lp;

    }
}
}
```

For better effect, i set the background color to pink. The background color is set in flyout menu page.

If you wanna more information about the `FlyoutPage`, you could refer to the MS docs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/flyoutpage

Comment: Thanks Wendy. I'm setting the width of the split view Flyout on tablet though and changing the width doesn't seem to be taking effect in this case.

Comment: I tested on Android 10.0 emulator. Could you provide more details of your tablet device?

Comment: I was using an Android 9.0 emulator but just tried on 10 with the same results. It's the tablet_m-dpi_10_1 emulator. Here is a quick sample app I made to demonstrate: https://github.com/TrueGeek/ResizedFlyoutTest

Comment: I created a 10.1 WXGA tablet with mdpi density. It still woks with the code i provided. I rechecked the code you provided. You missed the `Gravity = (int)GravityFlags.Left` in your `_flyoutLayou.LayoutParameters`. You could check my screenshot: https://imgurupload.org/files/Screenshot-1634288429.png

Comment: Ah, yes, I removed that. I'm doing a split screen view (previously called MasterDetailPage - now called FlyoutPage and Detail).

Comment: If you used the flyoutpage, the code I provided should work.