# How to change the size of FlyoutPages Drawer size in xamarin forms uwp?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I basically want to decrease the size of the drawer in my Xamarin forms UWP app. I have a FlyoutPage and a Custom Renderer for that but i can't find the property of the size of the drawer.
I guess i'm totally lost on Xamarin Forms because i'm a beginner and non-native english speaker.

So, here are my codes:

FlyoutMenuPage.xaml

'''

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="using:FlyoutPageNavigation"
             x:Class="FlyoutPageNavigation.FlyoutMenuPage"
             Padding="0,20,0,0"
             IconImageSource=""
             Title="Random"
             >
    
    <StackLayout >
        <ListView x:Name="listView" x:FieldModifier="public">
            <ListView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type local:FlyoutPageItem}">
                    <local:FlyoutPageItem Title="Menu" IconSource="" TargetType="{x:Type local:BasePage}" />
                    <local:FlyoutPageItem Title="Settings" IconSource="" TargetType="{x:Type local:SettingsPage}" />
                    <local:FlyoutPageItem Title="Information" IconSource="" TargetType="{x:Type local:InformationPage}" />
                </x:Array>
            </ListView.ItemsSource>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid Padding="5,10">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

'''

Custom Renderer

i tried to add some code in here for the drawer size but nothing works so i deleted everything.

```
'''

        [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(FlyoutMenuPage), typeof(FlyoutCustomRenderer))]
    namespace Random.UWP.Custom_Renderers 
    {
        class FlyoutCustomRenderer : PageRenderer
        {
            protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
            {
                base.OnElementChanged(e);
                if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
                {
                    return;
                }
    
    
            }
        }
    }

'''
```

Thanks.

Comment: Never used UWP but maybe like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69486888/changing-size-of-xamarin-flyout-page

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/98e71ff5-b6a5-428b-ad14-76cf789c66a8/how-to-customize-flyoutitem?forum=xamarinforms

Comment: I update my answer with some image's so you can see the difference in Width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a  `none-Shell` project ,you can refer to the following solution .

`FlyoutPage` was renamed from [MasterDetailPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.masterdetailpage?view=xamarin-forms) , and I found the solution [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/864e038b-de3e-49ab-8b20-672bf6a13421/adjust-width-of-master-on-masterdetailpage?forum=xamarinforms) , it used to work when it is named as `MasterDetailPage` , so I made a little modification , and it works now .

Add the following style into `App.xaml` in UWP project .

And `OpenPaneLength` repensents the width of the drawer , you can modify the value .

```
xmlns:uwp="using:Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP">

    <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="uwp:FlyoutPageControl">
            <Setter Property="ToolbarForeground" Value="{ThemeResource DefaultTextForegroundThemeBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="uwp:FlyoutPageControl">
                        <SplitView x:Name="SplitView" OpenPaneLength="100" IsPaneOpen="{Binding IsPaneOpen,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMode="Overlay">
                            <SplitView.Pane>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{TemplateBinding FlyoutToolbarVisibility}"  Background="{TemplateBinding ToolbarBackground}">
                                        <Button Name="PaneTogglePane" Style="{ThemeResource PaneButton}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding ToolbarForeground}"
                                            AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Path=(AutomationProperties.Name), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}"  
                                            AutomationProperties.HelpText="{Binding Path=(AutomationProperties.HelpText), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}"  
                                            AutomationProperties.LabeledBy="{Binding Path=(AutomationProperties.LabeledBy), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}"  
                                            AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="{Binding Path=(AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}"  />
                                        <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{TemplateBinding FlyoutTitle}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding FlyoutTitleVisibility}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding ToolbarForeground}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="FlyoutPresenter" Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Flyout}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </SplitView.Pane>
                            <SplitView.Content>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <Border x:Name="TopCommandBarArea" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="{TemplateBinding ToolbarBackground}">
                                        <uwp:FormsCommandBar x:Name="CommandBar" Background="{TemplateBinding ToolbarBackground}" MinHeight="{ThemeResource TitleBarHeight}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                            <uwp:FormsCommandBar.Resources>
                                                <Thickness x:Key="AppBarButtonContentViewboxMargin">12,14,0,14</Thickness>
                                                <Thickness x:Key="AppBarButtonContentViewboxCompactMargin">0,14,0,14</Thickness>
                                                <Thickness x:Key="AppBarButtonContentViewboxCollapsedMargin">0,14,0,4</Thickness>
                                                <Thickness x:Key="AppBarButtonOverflowTextTouchMargin">0,11,0,13</Thickness>
                                                <Thickness x:Key="AppBarButtonOverflowTextLabelPadding">0,5,0,7</Thickness>
                                                <Thickness x:Key="AppBarButtonTextLabelMargin">2,0,2,8</Thickness>
                                                <Thickness x:Key="AppBarButtonTextLabelOnRightMargin">8,15,12,17</Thickness>
                                                <Thickness x:Key="AppBarToggleButtonOverflowTextTouchMargin">0,11,0,13</Thickness>
                                                <Thickness x:Key="AppBarToggleButtonOverflowCheckTouchMargin">12,12,12,12</Thickness>
                                                <Thickness x:Key="AppBarToggleButtonOverflowCheckMargin">12,6,12,6</Thickness>
                                                <Thickness x:Key="AppBarToggleButtonTextLabelMargin">2,0,2,8</Thickness>
                                                <Thickness x:Key="AppBarToggleButtonTextLabelOnRightMargin">8,15,12,17</Thickness>
                                                <Thickness x:Key="AppBarToggleButtonOverflowTextLabelPadding">0,5,0,7</Thickness>
                                                <x:Double x:Key="AppBarButtonContentHeight">20</x:Double>
                                                <x:Double x:Key="AppBarThemeMinHeight">60</x:Double>
                                                <!-- We probably want to keep this in sync with TitleBarHeight in Resources.xaml -->
                                                <x:Double x:Key="AppBarThemeCompactHeight">48</x:Double>
                                            </uwp:FormsCommandBar.Resources>
                                            <uwp:FormsCommandBar.Content>
                                                <Border x:Name="TitleArea" Height="{ThemeResource TitleBarHeight}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailTitleVisibility}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                                    <Grid x:Name="TitleViewPresenter" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

                                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                                        <Button Grid.Column="0" Name="ContentTogglePane" Style="{ThemeResource PaneButton}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding ToolbarForeground}"  
                                                            Visibility="{TemplateBinding ContentTogglePaneButtonVisibility}" />

                                                        <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="{TemplateBinding DetailTitleIcon}" />

                                                        <Border Grid.Column="2" Height="{ThemeResource TitleBarHeight}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailTitleVisibility}">
                                                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding DetailTitle}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" Foreground="{TemplateBinding ToolbarForeground}" Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" />
                                                        </Border>

                                                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="3" Content="{Binding DetailTitleView, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource ViewToRenderer}}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailTitleViewVisibility}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />

                                                    </Grid>
                                                </Border>
                                            </uwp:FormsCommandBar.Content>
                                        </uwp:FormsCommandBar>
                                    </Border>

                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="DetailPresenter" Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Detail}" />

                                    <Border x:Name="BottomCommandBarArea" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></Border>
                                </Grid>
                            </SplitView.Content>
                        </SplitView>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this at the top of `AppShell.xaml` for example *360*

```
FlyoutWidth="360"
```

Like this :

[image]

The documents here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout#flyout-width-and-height

[image]

[image]